# Read a parameter from command line runner using spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to read a parameter from command line runner using spring Batch.I am not using spring boot.

I have searched in google but all went vain.Posted the code of spring batch jobs xml

```
<!-- Api batch job -->
    <job id="ProspectApiJob" restartable="true"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="ProspectApiStep">
            <tasklet ref="ProspectApiTasklet" />
        </step>
    </job>
    <bean id="ProspectApiTasklet"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter">
        <property name="targetObject">
            <bean class="com.cashe.service.impl.TestServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="ProspectApi" />
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

I should  be able to extract the value of comp.name i.e ICIC in the method ProspectApi  When I run the below  command. How can this be acheived?

```
java -cp "/data/Batch/batchlib/*" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner spring-batch-jobs.xml ProspectApiJob -comp.name=ICICI  ProspectApiJobParam=$date
```

Please find the below method.This method runs successfully when there are no arguements

```
public void ProspectApi(String... args) {

    System.out.println("start");
    if(args!=null) {
        System.out.println("der");
    }else {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("end");
    }
```

Comment: And what happens if there are arguments?

Comment: I got the exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching arguments found for method: ProspectApi.

Comment: What i want is,I want to retrieve the values inside method for the parameters passed    in the command to run the script("mentioned in the post")

Comment: Please edit the question and post the full stack trace.